# Drupal 8 custom block with html and javascript

Tags: blocks, 8

In Drupal 8 what is the process for creating blocks with html and javascript?

Here is my sample code for creating the block

```
class TopNewsBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
     //Fetch data
     return array(
      'type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => '<table id="example_table"></table>',
      '#attached' => array(
        'library' =>  array(      
          'custom_cms_blocks/dataTables.dataTablesjs',
          'custom_cms_blocks/top-news-library'
        ),
      ),
     ); 
  } 

}
```

It works but the problem I have is - I want to seperate out the html code from the php code. Is it possible to include a html file within the block just like the way a javascript file is attached as a library?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use [`hook_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8) in your module, and declare a new Twig template that you want to use for your block.

Here's an example that needs to go to `YOUR_MODULE.module` file:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_theme() {
  return [
    'YOUR_TEMPLATE_KEY' => [
      // Here you can pass any variables you want, if necessary.
      'variables' => ['var1' => NULL],
    ],
  ];
}
```

Then create a folder called `/templates` in your custom module, and `YOUR_TEMPLATE_KEY.html.twig` file where you can have any markup you want. See below how to use the variables you pass to the template:

```
<div id="your-block">
  {{ var1 }}
</div>
```

Finally, to use it:

```
public function build() {
  return [
    '#theme' => 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_KEY',
    '#var1' => 'Variable one passed here',
  ];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get the error Template "modules/custom/MY_MODULE_NAME/templates/MY_TEMPLATE_NAME.html.twig" is not defined (Drupal\Core\Template\Loader\ThemeRegistryLoader: Unable to find template "modules/custom/MY_MODULE_NAME/templates/MY_TEMPLATE_NAME.html.twig" in the Drupal theme registry.

Comment: Did you clear caches?

Comment: Yes. I uninstalled and reinstalled the module as well. Didnt help.

Comment: Strange; I tested the code above before posting and it worked well. Make sure that all naming is correct and that there are no typos.

Comment: The code is correct.

Comment: Sorry! My mistake. The issue was with replacing underscores in the template name with hyphen when creating the template file. It is working now and marking it as answered. Thanks a lot @Aram Boyajyan

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you sorted it out :)